# How do I combine a list of 1 item dicts into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a result of a pymongo query I have a list of 1 item dicts:

```
[{'id': 453},
 {'id': 365},
 {'id': 311},
 {'id': 523},
 {'id': 367},
 {'id': 891},
 {'id': 621},
 {'id': 215},
 {'id': 819},
 {'id': 218},
 {'id': 711},
 {'id': 212},
 {'id': 409},
 {'id': 200},
 {'id': 893},
 {'id': 219},
 {'id': 832},
...]
```

I would like to simply have a list of these values :  `[453,365,...]` is there a function that accomplishes this? Otherwise, I guess I could loop through it:

```
my_list = []
[my_list.append(i['id']) for i in ids]
```

Comment: your list comprehension is about the best solution for this

Comment: But you don't need append: `my_list = [i['id'] for i in ids]`

Comment: I guess so, for some reason I thought there was a function, kind of the inverse of the zip function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it a oneliner:

```
my_list = [i['id'] for i in ids]
```